# LinkedIn People or members search API

Tags: python, integration, linkedin-api

I cannot find the LinkedIn People search API. I need to create an app integrated with LinkedIn and search people using that API.

There is no documentation available around this.

I looked at the Microsoft documentation but there any only few APIs available that are not relevant to my usecase.

Comment: Searching for users on the LinkedIn API has been deprecated since 2021.

Comment: @Cow is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Dunno, maybe there are third party API's, but recommendations are off topic on [SO].